# init seg_duration option for dash similar to -hls_init_time option

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

Is there any option to set first segment duration for dash files, There is similar option for HLS: [hls_init_time](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-5)?

I could not found any such option in [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#dash-2).

---

Why I want such option to be there:

From generated DASH files: in Android ExoPlayer, It always plays first chunk of lowest quality(bitrate/resolution), after first chunk, basis user's internet speed, it picks the next chunk. If there is no init_seg_duration option, I have to rely only on seg_duration and I can not keep it bit large. Why I will like to keep it large: to reduce the number of files generated.

With such option, I could had given `-init_seg_duraion 2 -seg_duration 6`, so video quality would had increased after 2 seconds and total number of files generated would also not had exploded.

Comment: There's no such option.

Answer (score 1):

According to latest source file: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/dashenc.c

There is no such option implemented.

(I just wondered, why such option is needed?)

Comment: Edited question to answer why such option is needed?